# Excel how to look for specific variable length ending substring and return string without that ending substring?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure how to title this question.

I have a complicated challenge that I'm not sure how to approach in excel.

I have a column with long variable length strings, example

```
c68d7a51-5cef-4a5c-b417-b2751fe9754b  
c68d7a51-5cef-4a5c-b417-b2751fe9754b-0  
c68d7a51-5cef-4a5c-b417-b2751fe9754b-1
09573f-1780c84f-e5ff-85821a-6236e0399d
09573f-1780c84f-e5ff-85821a-6236e0399d-10
09573f-1780c84f-e5ff-85821a-6236e0399d-123
```

Where for the ones that end in a "-***" I need to have a new column which returns the string without that ending RIGHT substring else null. The ending substring is anywhere from 1 to 3 characters long after the "-" specific character. I also need to note based on the comments, that I can't work from the left because the strings change in length and in "-" placement. The only constant is that some of these strings have child substring values from 1 to 3 digitals after the last "-".

What I have so far for an outline looks like this

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,4) contains "-", RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - number_of_chars_to_remove), else null.
```

If you don't mind, how do I go about accomplishing this?

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: is it always 4 `-` then the `-` you want to remove?

Comment: Hi Scott, 4 is the maximum length of the ending substring from the right of the whole string including the "-" divider. But sometimes the string's last 4 will not contain a "-" which means return null because everything is ok. But when the last 4 contain a "-" I need to remove the "-" and everything after it for a new column. Where the characters after "-" (in the last 4) will be either 1, 2, or 3 digits.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  Right now you have a pattern that can be exploited.  You have 4 or 5 "-" and you want the string before the 5th "-" or null if no 5th "-".  So I ask again, are there always 4 "-" with the  5th "-" being the decider in your strings?

Comment: Oh, in the left of the string? yea misunderstood you, no left of the string is random in that it changes in both length and number of dashes, which is why I can't work from the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",RIGHT(A1,4))),LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))-1),"")
```

It first test if there is a `-` in the last four, if so it finds that last `-` and changes it to `}}}`.  Then it finds that and makes that the end of the LEFT equation.

[image]

Comment: You're a magician! thank you so much! You saved my bacon!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, based on your sample data, that you could count the string and if it has 5 dashes, return the first 38 characters, otherwise, return NULL.  That would be a lot simpler. 38 is significant as its the length of the string up to the fifth dash.

Comment: Good suggestion, the only constant though I have in the dashes is either dash in the last 4 or not. Because the string - locations to the left of that will all be random.. It's really messy I know.. but that's why I'm trying to work from the right instead of the left. because the right is the most constant outcome I have to work with in knowing that the last 4 will either have a dash or not. and if it does have a dash, it will only have 1 to 3 digits after it.